# Thymelaf - two if in one div

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to do this:

```
<div th:text="${abc.tempLow != null} ? ${abc.tempLow + '°C '}"></div>
<div th:text="${abc.tempHigh != null} ? ${abc.tempHigh + '°C '}"></div>
```

But in one div. Something like that doesn't work:

```
<div th:text="${abc.tempLow != null} ? ${abc.tempLow + '°C '} 
+ ${abc.tempHigh() != null} ? ${abc.tempHigh + '°C'}"></div>
```

Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use i.e. two spans inside this div with `th:text` ?

Comment: I was able to do that using a simple 'and' keyword.

Comment: @Jay it's not the same. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this :

```
<div>
     <th:block th:text="${abc.tempLow != null ? abc.tempLow + '°C ' : ''}">tempLow</th:block>
     <th:block th:text="${abc.tempHigh != null ? abc.tempHigh + '°C ' : ''}">tempHigh</th:block>
</div>
```